# Dell OptiPlex 7010 random BSOD 0x7E

Tags: windows-7, usb, memory, drivers, bsod

We bought a batch of 80 of these computers.  We're experiencing this problem on 6 of them right now, but that number keeps growing.  The BSOD error code is 0x0000007E, which is a driver problem.  I suspect it's the Intel USB 3 driver causing it, but no driver file is indicated on the BSOD message itself, and there is no crash dump on the hard drive to examine despite the fact that it's set to create one.

We are using a standard corporate desktop image (Windows 7 Enterprise), so all machines are identical.

**Confirmed Symptoms:**

- The problem is intermittent.  The USB ports all work fine until one day they don't.
- Re-imaging the machine returns it to working order, but the problem comes back within a few days, or sometimes even weeks later.
- Once the BSOD gets tripped the firs time, the computer is dead.  It will not boot at all -- not even in Safe Mode.
- Disabling the USB ports in the BIOS allows the system to boot normally (although obviously that's not a workable solution).
- On an affected machine (after re-imaging it), attempting to upgrade, remove, or otherwise modify any of the USB 3 controllers or root hubs triggers the BSOD immediately -- even if there are no USB devices connected.  This is the only way I've been able to trigger the problem on-demand.

**Steps I've Taken to Resolve It:**

- Run diagnostics and they all pass with flying colors.
- Upgraded the firmware to the latest version (currently A18).
- I tried upgrading to the latest USB3 driver straight from Intel's web site, but it triggers a BSOD instantly.
- Removed all USB devices from the system, even going so far as to dig up an old PS/2 mouse and keyboard.
- Changed out RAM from a known working machine, and have tried it in different RAM slots on the motherboard.

Dell says it's not a hardware problem, and I am (sort of) inclined to agree.  If it were a hardware problem, reimaging wouldn't fix it.  But it's the same image on 74 other machines that are working fine.  It's almost like some USB parameters in the registry are getting changed from time to time, and one particular parameter causes it to barf.

Any ideas?

Comment: 'We are using a standard corporate desktop image (Windows 7 Enterprise), so all machines are identical.' you installed this or it was pre-installed when you bought them?

Comment: No we installed it. We have an SCCM server for deploying new hardware, and I built the image myself.  We also have same-generation Dell Latitude laptops that use that USB 3 driver as well and we haven't had a single problem with any of them.  I don't *think* it's the driver, but this wouldn't be the first time Intel has subtly botched a driver like that.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I am the IT department

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely was the Intel USB3 driver.  The one dated 09/2013 causes the issue, but the one dated 02/2014 works.  We haven't had a single issue since we upgraded it.

Because the machine had been imaged with bad drivers already in place, I could not install the good one because it caused a BSOD immediately.  I had to slip the new driver into the image offline. Also pulling the driver out completely would have fixed it too as I could have then just installed the correct one fresh.

Anyway, bottom line:
**Do not use the September 2013 version of Intel's USB 3 driver.  It is buggy!**

Comment: +1, ran into this exact issue making an image for several Optiplex PCs and this saved me a lot of painful troubleshooting.  Thanks!